# Positioning div below top div

Tags: html, height

I have a .top div with variable height, and i want to position .nav bellow the .top div so i wanna something like .nav-top = .top-height.
How to do that, can be in jQuery?

```
.nav {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    right:0;
    top:80px;
    position:absolute;
    background: #1581C4;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    z-index:6;
}
.top {
    content:url(../images/top480.jpg);
    z-index:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `.nav-top = nav-height`?? And please post your html too.

Comment: I mean .nav top = .top-height...

Answer (score 0):

I think javascript is worth a try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   window.onload=function{
      document.getElementById([yournavdivid]).style.top = document.getElementById([yourtopivid]);
   }
</script>
```